# How can I cancel a dataproc job before it starts running?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I have to wait for a job to start running before I can cancel it. Is there a way to cancel the job early? Why can I not cancel a job in `SETUP_DONE`?

Cancelling the job errors with `FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot cancel jobId 'x' in project 'y' in state: 'SETUP_DONE'; cancellable states: '[PENDING, RUNNING]'`

Deleting the job also errors with `FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot delete non-terminal jobId 'x' in project 'y'; current state: 'SETUP_DONE'`

This [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3754) on GitHub raises the same question.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. Can you consider adding retry in your cancel logic? Or consider deleting the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I went with retry logic. Why is it not possible? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Deleting the cluster isn't a good option. For example, other jobs might be running that we don't want to cancel.